# How to combine similar methods?

Tags: java

I have quite the same methods, but for different fields of class.
How can I make a method that will do both of these things, depending on parameters.

Thanks in advance.

```
    private int getLengthOfLongestName(List<Driver> drivers) {
        return drivers.stream()
                .map(t -> t.getName())
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .map(String::length)
                .orElse(0);
    }

    private int getLengthOfLongestTeam(List<Driver> drivers) {
        return drivers.stream()
                .map(t -> t.getTeamName())
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .map(String::length)
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

Comment: Pass in the thing that changes: the function you apply in map().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a `Function` as a parameter:

```java
    private int getLengthOfLongest(List<Driver> drivers, Function<Driver, String> func) {
        return drivers.stream()
                .map(func)
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                .max()
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

Then you can call it like `getLengthOfLongest(driverList, Driver::getName)`, or use `Driver::getTeamName` for the other version.

Note that it's a bit simpler to `mapToInt` to the string lengths before taking the `max`, as this avoids taking the string length twice, and then you have an `IntStream` so you don't need to provide an explicit comparator.

I would also recommend using a method reference like `Driver::getName` instead of a lambda like `t -> t.getName()` as this makes it more explicit what type of thing you are getting the name of.

Comment: alternatively, `... .mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);`

Comment: Thanks. It helps me.
Also thanks for the code review:)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `Function` as parameter to `getLongestValue` and just use `max` to get maximum value

```
private int getLongestValue(List<Driver> drivers, Function<Driver, String> func) {
    return drivers.stream()
            .map(func)
            .mapToInt(String::length)
            .max()
            .orElse(0);
}
```

So you can use it for mapping different values

```
getLongestValue(list, Driver::getName)
getLongestValue(list, Driver::getTeamName)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is also helpful.